# how to know the rtsp url of a IP camera to be opened in vlc

Tags: url, vlc, rtsp

Hello can anybody help me create/know the rtsp url so that i can view the IP camera i have in vlc media player

the guide i was following said to use this but vlc says it cant open it

rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.108:554//h264Preview_01_main

logging in through the ip address of the IP camera :

username: admin and password:  rtspport: 554
[image]

if you need a certain setting or  info about the camera tell me so i can try and look for it in the settings
[image]

Using Vlc i did:
Media -> Open Network Stream -> Network -> URL

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*"Hi, my cameras also had the wrong url in the manual, it was the end..."*

## IPCAM-100

```
Stream 1
========
rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.108:554/stream1

Stream 2
========
rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.108:554/stream2
```

---

```
Basic Information
=================
DeviceModel.. : IPCAM-100
DeviceSN..... : 30200307xxx
KernelVersion : Thu Jul 9 15:46:54 CST 2015
ServerVersion : W1.3.1859-20190419-NORMAL-GEN
WebVersion... : V2.3.4-20190320
OCXVersion... : -1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hey**

Normaly such RTSP url you can find when u google "ipcam-100 rtsp url" or in the camera manual.

First, you have typo in your url that u posted:

rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.108:554//h264Preview_01_main

After specify port its just on slash

rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.108:554/h264Preview_01_main

Also 554 is the Standart Rtsp port so if you have 554 you dont need to set them.
**rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.108/h264Preview_01_main**

try this if the camera a kingscam

**rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.108/cam/realmonitor**

Answer (score 0):

If you need a still image also, this could help

```
http://{ip}/?action=snapshot
```